# Reversing assembler DCD directive list into a c++ variable

Tags: disassembly, assembly, c++, hexrays

For example we have assembler variable "foo" defined as:

```
.text:00001078 foo      DCD 0xffffffff, 0xffffeeee
```

How it(variable `foo`) would look like in c++(or whatever higher lang)???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many possibilities.

`long long foo=0xffffffffffffeeee` (assuming big endian mode)

`long long foo=0xffffeeeeffffffff` (assuming big endian mode)

`int foo[2]={-1, -4370}`

`short foo[4]={-1, -1, -1, -4370}`

`char foo[16]="\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xee\xee\xee\xee"`

`struct { int a, short b, short c } foo = { -1, -1, -4370 }` (and variations depending on endianness)

You really can't determine the original type of initalized data without looking at the code that uses it.